# Use Absolute path instead for go "fmt" in import directive

Tags: go, compilation

This is an instructional question and not a procedural one as simply requiring `"fmt"` works just fine, but when with the hello world golang file I modify it as follows

```
    package main
    
    import "golang.org/fmt"
    
    func main() {
            fmt.Println("Hello, world")
    }
```

I get in response:

```
go:3:8: no required module provides package golang.org/fmt; to add it:
    go get golang.org/fmt
```

I can see the `fmt` package in `/usr/local/go/src/fmt` and it mirrors the files in `https://golang.org/src/fmt/`

I am probably very close in the above file, what is the correct *absolute* path that would work to include `fmt` ?  Thank you!

Comment: "what is the correct absolute path that would work to include fmt" is the wrong question. fmt is part of the stdlib and imported as "fmt" only and ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct absolute import path for the package is `fmt`.

[Relative import paths](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Relative_import_paths) start with `./` or `../`.  The import path `fmt` is an absolute import path.

[Remote import paths](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths) start with a domain name.  The package does not have a remote import path.

The tool chain creates a unique package for each import path. If the application could refer to the source code for the `fmt` package using a remote import path, the package with the remote path will be different from the standard `fmt` package. Every aspect of the package is unique. The code is duplicated.  There is a  [ScanState](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#ScanState) type for each package and these types cannot be used interchangeably.
The [pp cache](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/3b770f2ccb1fa6fecc22ea822a19447b10b70c5c/src/fmt/print.go#L131) is duplicated.  And so on.

Comment: Thank you.  I see there are quite a few conceptual bits related to Go packages and modules.  Having come from PHP where this is really not a thing, the closest I dealt with this was composer.  As I mentioned in another comment earlier, this is an academic question but one that has an answer, so felt appropriate and hope it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `fmt` is the fully qualified path. Compare the `fmt` docs [1] with `golang.org/x/text` docs [2].

Go standard library does have a `go.mod` [3], but trying to import `std/fmt` doesn't work either.

1. https://pkg.go.dev/fmt
2. https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/text
3. https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/go.mod